# How to add passive option to addEventListener in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i want to to add [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Syntax) to `scroll` event of an element in **TypeScript** like this:

```
element.addEventListener("scroll", () => { }, { capture: true, passive: true });
```

But TypeScript throw an syntax error: `Argument of type '{ capture: true, passive: true }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'`.
 I know the reason of error is TypeScript does not define an `options` argument for `addEventListener`. It just only have `useCapture` argument. We can see it in *`lib.dom.d.ts`*:

```
addEventListener<K extends keyof ElementEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: Element, ev: ElementEventMap[K]) => any, useCapture?: boolean): void;
addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture?: boolean): void;
```

I found an open issue and a [walk around](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9548#issuecomment-256793821) in github but it seems complicate and i am not sure it is right. 
By the way, i also want to know why TypeScript did not define `options` argument for `addEventListener`? 

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A quick (but maybe ugly) fix would be to just cast `element` to `any` while calling `addEventListener`. `(<any>element).addEventListener("scroll", () => { }, { capture: true, passive: true });`. Not 100% sure, but I think that will work

Comment: @FredrikLundin: It will remove typescript error but does it actual add options to the event? How can i test to ensure it?

Comment: Typescript is just a helping out at compile time. Using the `any` type is there for wildcard situations, where you want to opt out of types. The underlaying `element` object is just the same, typed or not typed

Comment: did you check 'Safely detecting option support' section on link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener?

Comment: @FredrikLundin: You might right. Can you post an answer please?

Comment: @deezg: I already checked it. It is necessary but it only can be writen in javascript. In typescript it will throw the error because the complier checked the type

Comment: sorry, wasn't focused completely when i was reading the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a *workaround* for situations like this, you can always cast your object to the `any` type.

```
(<any>element).addEventListener("scroll", () => { }, { capture: true, passive: true });
```

The `any` type is used to opt-out of typescripts typing system. Meaning you will work on an unknown type that you can treat any way you like, without the typescript compiler complaining.

You can read more on the [**any `type` here**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)!

Comment: Your answer is right. I upvoted it. But as you say, it maybe ugly. I will wait some hours for other answers. If i don't find a better one, i will accept yours. Thank you!

Comment: For people using TSX (JSX for TypeScript), you'll have to write it as `(element as any).addEventListener("scroll", () => { }, { capture: true, passive: true });`, since the `<>` characters are interpreted differently in TSX.

Answer (score 3):

Since interfaces in Typescript are open-ended you can add functions do the `Document` interface by re-declaring it in your application:

```
 interface Document {
    addEventListener(event: "scroll", listener: (event: Event) => void, options?: {
        passive?: boolean;
        once?: boolean;
        capture?: boolean;
      }      
  );
}
```

The you will be able to use the overload you defined, or any overload (or any other method) defined dor `Document` in lib.d.ts:

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", ()=> {}, {
    capture: true,
    once: true
});

document.addEventListener("scroll", ()=> {}, true);
```

I can't speak to why this was not included, there might be some corner cases where it will interfere method resolution for  other overloads of `addEventListener`. (Note: I did not test this extensively so you may run into this issue).

Answer (score 2):

I think the approach from linked github is fine. If you want, you could do inline variation. but it boils down to the same:

```
(element.addEventListener as (
      type: string,
      listener: (event: Event) => void,
      options?: { useCapture?: boolean, passive?:boolean }
    ) => void)("scroll", () => { }, {/*here use userCapture & passive*/})
```

so what you are effectively doing here is casting `element.addEventListener` method into arrow function and extending its signature so that typescript compiler can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `as unknown as EventListenerOptions` to get this to work as well, e.g.

```
element.addEventListener("scroll", () => { }, ({ capture: true, passive: true } as unknown) as EventListenerOptions);
```